# Flutter main.dart localhost has pool of information in chrome

Tags: flutter

Using flutter to create an application. Stored data is taken from excel file ( data in first three columns)  and trying to run Main.dart and the local host in chrome shows data as in the attached screenshot. I was actually expecting a drop down with options fetched from excel file

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHGZk.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.